# Can't update specific row in database using UPDATE SQL statement for a ListView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to create an UPDATE function on my website so an admin can create/edit the product categories.  I have encountered a problem where the database table will not update, and I can't seem to find exactly where the problem is.  I am not getting any error messages, it just redirects me to the Default.aspx page, which is expected.

The following is the code on the .aspx file

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="genrelist" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString='<%$ConnectionStrings:itemsconnection%>'
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [productname] FROM [producttype]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<p>Current Categories</p>
<asp:ListView ID="categorylist" runat="server" DataSourceID="genrelist"
    DataKeyNames="ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">            
                <asp:TextBox ID = "categoryedit"
                    CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Width="300px"
                    Text='<%# Eval("productname")  %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:Button ID="updatecategories" CssClass="btn btn-default"
    runat="server" OnClick="updatecategories_Click" Text="Save Changes"/>
```

The following is the C# code

```
int item = 0;
if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
{
    item = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}

string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["itemsconnection"].ConnectionString;

//setup connection object called 'myConnection'
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

//open database connection
myConnection.Open();

var ctrl = (Control)sender;
var lvi = (ListViewItem)ctrl.NamingContainer;
var txt = (TextBox)lvi.FindControl("categoryedit");
txt.Visible = false;

string cat = txt.Text;

//create the SQL statement
string query = "UPDATE producttype SET productname = @itemnamenew WHERE ID=@id";

//setup SQL command and use the SQL and myCconnection object
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemnamenew", cat);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item);


myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I want to apologize for the long question where the code is probably possible to be stripped down further, but I'm really not sure where thee issue lies.  Thanks.

Comment: So what have your diagnostics told you so far? The HTML part is probably irrelevant - and the simplest way to prove that is to write a short but complete console app with hard-coded values, which *just* tries to perform the update. If that works, then go back to the ASP.NET part of it. As an aside, I would strongly urge you to use `using` statements for your command and connection. It's not clear what your question has to do with mysql btw, given that you're using `SqlConnection` which is usually used with SQL server...

Comment: Do you have another redirect to default.aspx or just the one shown on the code, which occurs on the top? Because this would mean that your query does not contain an `ID` parameter and thus `item == 0`. I don't know if that's a valid ID.

Comment: @derpirscher no, just the one redirect to default.aspx.

Comment: So try Debugging and check whether `ID` is contained in the query and can be parsed to a valid integer. And if yes, check if this id is contained in the database.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm off my university campus, so I can't use debugging features.

Comment: So do it, when you have access again and you'll find that `ID == null` and `item == 0`

Comment: `Request.QueryString["ID"]` is totally irrelevant to what you want to do. Take ID values from your `ListView.DataKeys[row.DisplayIndex].Value`  (in the circle, of course)